# Passing string literals to index signatures

Tags: typescript, index-signature

I've currently got `MyTest` which simply maps over an object:

```js
type MyTest<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

type Result = MyTest<{hello: 'world', foo: 2}>;
//   ^? type Result = { hello: 'world', foo: 2 }
```

However If I pass a string literal like `hello` instead of an object, I get `hello` back. Question is why?

```js
type Result2 = MyTest<"hello">;
//   ^? type Result2 = "hello"
```

I'm thinking of 2 scenarios here:

1. The iteration does indeed happen with the keys being the property names a string may have such as `toString()`. In this case I'd expect an object back with ~35 keys all of which would carry the value of `never`?
2. The iteration never happens cause there's nothing to iterate on. What's the default value then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour has been discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40012). Using mapped types to map over primitives will just return the primitve itself.

> Mapped types declared as { [ K in keyof T ]: U } where T is a type parameter are known as homomorphic mapped types, which means that the mapped type is a structure preserving function of T. When type parameter T is instantiated with a primitive type the mapped type evaluates to the same primitive.

Comment: Thank you Tobias! Your help has been invaluable!